# Include PHP file from another linux account

Tags: php, unix

I am running my server on cPanel.

I have two users accounts:

```
/home/user1
/home/user2
```

From user2 I need to include `/home/user1/public_html/config.php`.

Is their anyway to apply this?

Comment: What happens if you just do it?

Comment: not readable
in case am calling a function from the included file am getting error that function is not defined

Comment: What do you mean by "not readable"? Is there any error message involved? How **exactly** do you run the include?

Comment: define('MAX_PATH', '/home/semantic/public_html/adserver');
@include_once(MAX_PATH . '/www/delivery/alocal.php');

Comment: Why do you suppress errors using the `@` sign and wonder that an error occurs at another place? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fully possible to access php files located in other parts of the hard drive than where the site is run. However, this depends on two things. First of, the web user needs read permissions for the file, and you need to define the root folder where that php file is located as a accessable folder for the website.

Setting file permissions for the file can be done with:

```
chmod +R 775 /home/user1/public_html/config.php
```

Defining the accessible folders for PHP depends on wether you are running Apache or Nginx.

**In Nginx for example:**

`fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir =$document_root:/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php:/var/www/vhosts/yourdomain/httpdocs/:/home/user1/public_html`";

**In Apache:**

[Apache readme](https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-set-open-basedir-in-apache/)

Now you should be able to require the file like you normally would require any file:

```
require('/home/user1/public_html/config.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just copy paste the `/home/user1/public_html/config.php` file to `/home/user2/public_html/`? If you don't have permissions to access or do any operation on the file, then you are simply not authorized to attempt this.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If user1 has modified the config.php it has to be copied again. On the other hand, if you have enough privileges to copy a file you may as well include it directly, instead of checking the original file for changes and copy it again. So this attempt does not help to solve the original problem but creates the need to synchronize a file between two user accounts. (i.e. the answer only adds complexity)

Comment: @feeela Where should there be a need for synchronicity? I have never seen an application which has user based config files in a file system and there is a need to fetch other user's configuration values to the current user. To be honest, the author hasn't mentioned clearly about why he is facing such a situation? Badly formed questions do get vague answers.